# Pervasive ODBC on Linux Error [01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/psql/lib/odbcci.so' : file not found

Tags: linux, odbc, pervasive

I'm attempting to get Pervasive v10 client ODBC working on Centos 6. As I've learned, there is no 64 bit ODBC client so I have to use the 32 bit one. I've finally gotten it to install without error but attempting usage gives the following:

```
# isql -v mydsn
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/psql/lib/odbcci.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

ldd shows this:

```
# ldd /usr/local/psql/lib/odbcci.so
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x007d3000)
libpscore.so.3 => /usr/local/psql/lib/libpscore.so.3 (0x00c32000)
libpscl.so.3 => /usr/local/psql/lib/libpscl.so.3 (0x005f9000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/libuuid.so.1 (0x0076d000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00110000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x003e0000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/psql/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0012b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00876000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/psql/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00434000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00954000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00f70000)
```

Comment: My guess is that there's a pathing issue.  If you `su psql` before running isql does it work?

Comment: I think you are right! :) When trying as psql I get a different error: [08S01][unixODBC][Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][Client LNA]The ODBC Client Interface cannot communicate with SQL Connection Manager due to a network error (RPC = 65, Error = 100). Contact your system administrator if you still need assistance.

Comment: If I telnet to port 1583 it connects so I do not believe the error is all that accurate. :/

Comment: Apparently v10 of psql does not like spaces in the DSN config. I added a DSN with dnsadd and it worked! Thanks mirthel!

Comment: Thanks Tim! That did it for me: I just removed all spaces from the config file and the connection issues disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem setting up ODBC and Pervasive for an Ubuntu client.

The reason it works after you `su psql` is because they install a `.bashrc` in the psql user account. The critical ingredient there for this question is `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` which tells the dynamic linker where to find the library.

The error in the comments regarding the SQL Connection Manager is one I ran into as well:

`[08S01][unixODBC][Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][Client LNA]The ODBC Client Interface cannot access the data source because SQL Connection Manager is not running at the specified port number. Contact your system administrator for assistance.`

I think Pervasive wants its own copy of the odbc.ini in its own etc directory. That `dsnadd` script probably does that. I didn't have `dsnadd` in the 64bit install, but I added a symlink from `/etc/odbc.ini` to `/usr/local/psql/etc/odbc.ini` and it worked.