# ISQL command result in: can't open lib 'odbcci.so' with unixODBC and Pervasive Client on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, unixodbc, pervasive, isql

I can't figure it out how to connect to a **Pervasive DB** on a Windows Server machine from an Ubuntu Linux 64bit via **ODBC**.

I installed `unixodbc`, then `32bit Pervasive Client 11sp2` from [here](http://www.pervasivedb.com/psqlv11/Pages/PSQL-v11-Linux-Downloads.aspx) and after moving the tar content to */usr/local/psql* and executing the `clientpreinstall.sh` and the `clientpostinstall.sh` I did the `dsnadd` command, adding the **dba** source.

Now, if I try to test the ODBC connection with `isql -v dba` i get the following:

> [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
>   [01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/psql/lib/odbcci.so' : file not found

**odbcci.so** exists in that dir.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: It sounds like you might have a 32 vs 64-bit version mismatch: http://cs.pervasive.com/forums/p/14171/48829.aspx

Comment: for sure its 32bit vs 64bit version library issue, Please match your arch with your OS arch. If you have 64 bit OS use 64 bit version libs.

Comment: I finally solved with an *Ubuntu 32 install*. Too intricate solution to run it on 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

This is a similar problem to the one in another question:
[Pervasive ODBC on Linux Error [01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/psql/lib/odbcci.so' : file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092840/pervasive-odbc-on-linux-error-01000unixodbcdriver-managercant-open-lib)

The answer is that you need to either run as the user `psql` which was created by the Pervasive install script, or source the `.bashrc` from that user's home prior to attempting an ODBC connection.